# Unable to Control Button Style and Hover Style

Tags: jquery, css, background, css-selectors, hover

I was attempting to change the button's background color and hover state. The only thing that worked up until this point was inline styling the button, but then I was unable to control the hover state of the button. I also tried putting !important on the button as can be seen in the code below, but that did not work. I'm sure I'm targeting the correct selector so I'm not sure why the background color is not changing.

```
<style>

    @media(max-width: 800px){

        .hidden-el{
            display: none;
        }
        .show-more-content-div{
            height: 33px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        a#showMoreContent.button{
            background-color: #428071!important;
            background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#428071,#035642);
        }
        a#showMoreContent.button:hover{
            background-color: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#428071,#035642);
            background-image: #428071;
        }

    }

</style>
<script>

    var $title                      = $('h1.wrapper').first();                                                      //get the title
    var $secondToLastRow            = $('.row').eq(-2);                                                             //get the second to last row
    var $firstParagraphAfterTitle   = $title.nextAll().find('p').first();                                           //get the first paragraph after the title

    var $start                      = $firstParagraphAfterTitle.parents('.group.divider');                          //determine the start of where to start hiding
    var $end                        = $secondToLastRow.parents('#content_mainholder'); //determine the end of where to start hiding

    var arrOfElsToBeHidden          = $start.nextUntil($end);                                                       //grab everything to be hidden and dump into an array

    $(arrOfElsToBeHidden).each(function(){                                                                          //loop through and add a hide class to each element to be hidden 
        $(this).addClass('hidden-el') 
    });

    var showMoreContent = [
        '<div class="show-more-content-div">',
        '<a href="#" class="button" id="showMoreContent">',
        'Show More Content',
        '</a>',
        '</div>'
    ].join("");                                                                                                     //created the show more content button

    $(showMoreContent).insertAfter($firstParagraphAfterTitle);

    $('#showMoreContent').on('hover', function(){
        console.log('hovered'); //works
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Where's the html code? Empower us. Give us everything we'll need to help you out. Actually, you can just leave out the javascript and provide the html code it renders. Then we can inspect the element, verify that your rules are in fact working, or otherwise, being overqualified by another rule with more specificity.  It's safe to say though that if you have the `!important` declaration on a natural state rule, whatever you declare for the hover state will be overqualified - unless you declare `!important` for that rule as well.

Comment: Your CSS is simply wrong

Answer (score 2):

I think you have `background-color` and `background-image` transposed in your `:hover` psuedo selector. That and your values for the gradient are identical. Simplified version here where I've corrected the values and reversed the gradient for the hover state:

```css
a#showMoreContent.button{
  background-color: #428071;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#428071,#035642);
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
a#showMoreContent.button:hover{
  background-color: #428071;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#035642,#428071);
}
```

```html
<a id="showMoreContent" class="button">Show more content</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the responses, I ended up getting it to work by adding an additional class to the button a link. I called it .show-more-content then styled it with Robert Wade's response and it worked. Still not understanding why the original selector I was using didn't work, but I guess I had to add a selector to make everything show up as expected.